# get row count of a dynamic column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a sql server database and i am using following query to get a list of attendance dates on which any given employee is late.

```
SELECT MIN(att.Date) 
  from Attendance att
  where att.Date between '12/01/2011 00:00:00' and '12/31/2011 00:00:00' 
  and att.EmpID = 4700 
  GROUP BY EmpID, CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 111) 
  having min(CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 8)) > '09:00:00'
```

the query returns a list of dates with no column name. 
i need is count the dates of this list.
how can this be done with this query?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT MIN(att.Date) [minDate]
    FROM Attendance att
    WHERE att.Date between '12/01/2011 00:00:00'
    AND '12/31/2011 00:00:00'
    AND att.EmpID = 4700
    GROUP BY EmpID, CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 111)
    HAVING MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 8)) > '09:00:00')

SELECT COUNT(minDate) FROM CTE
```

Alt without using CTE:

```
SELECT COUNT(minDate) FROM (
    SELECT MIN(att.Date) [minDate]
    FROM Attendance att
    WHERE att.Date between '12/01/2011 00:00:00'
    AND '12/31/2011 00:00:00'
    AND att.EmpID = 4700
    GROUP BY EmpID, CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 111)
    HAVING MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, att.Date , 8)) > '09:00:00') AS tbl
```

Comment: there is one problem i just found, i cant use this query in C# as nHibernate query. it says--- query must begin with SELECT or FROM:
now what? :-s